# Error reading Excel file with openpyxl 2.6.2 (was working under openpyxl 2.5.12)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I wrote a script that checks if Excel files contain the worksheet "Budget". This is working with Python 3.7 and openpyxl 2.5.12. However, since Anaconda updated openpyxl to version 2.6.2 it is no longer working (see error message below). I am having issues resolving this error message. Any help is appreciated.

```
# Import modules:
import os
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

# Set correct path to Excel files:

excel_folder = PureWindowsPath("C:\\Users\\c3post\\Desktop\\Excel")
correct_excel_folder = Path(excel_folder)
print('Working directory: ', correct_excel_folder, '\n\n')

# Change current working directory so that opening relative paths will work:
os.chdir(correct_excel_folder)

# Add files to list:
files = os.listdir(correct_excel_folder)

# Filter 'xlsx' files and add them to new list:
files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

# Filter out xlsx files that do not contain the worksheet "Budget"
files_budget = []

for file in files_xlsx:
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    ws = wb.worksheets
    if 'Budget' in str(ws):
        files_budget.append(file)

print('Files that contain worksheet "Budget": ', files_budget, '\n\n')
print('Files that do not contain worksheet "Budget": ', set(files_xlsx) - set(files_budget))
```

Error message:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fa1881e560e0> in <module>
     29 
     30 for file in files_xlsx:
---> 31     wb = load_workbook(file)
     32     ws = wb.worksheets
     33     if 'Budget' in str(ws):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    310     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    311                         data_only, keep_links)
--> 312     reader.read()
    313     return reader.wb

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in read(self)
    272         self.read_theme()
    273         apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
--> 274         self.read_worksheets()
    275         self.parser.assign_names()
    276         if not self.read_only:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in read_worksheets(self)
    226                 ws._rels = rels
    227                 ws_parser = WorksheetReader(ws, fh, self.shared_strings, self.data_only)
--> 228                 ws_parser.bind_all()
    229 
    230             # assign any comments to cells

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in bind_all(self)
    401 
    402     def bind_all(self):
--> 403         self.bind_cells()
    404         self.bind_merged_cells()
    405         self.bind_hyperlinks()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in bind_cells(self)
    324 
    325     def bind_cells(self):
--> 326         for idx, row in self.parser.parse():
    327             for cell in row:
    328                 style = self.ws.parent._cell_styles[cell['style_id']]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in parse(self)
    148                 element.clear()
    149             elif tag_name == ROW_TAG:
--> 150                 row = self.parse_row(element)
    151                 element.clear()
    152                 yield row

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in parse_row(self, row)
    270         if keys != set(['r', 'spans']) and keys != set(['r']):
    271             # don't create dimension objects unless they have relevant information
--> 272             self.row_dimensions[attrs['r']] = attrs
    273 
    274         cells = [self.parse_cell(el) for el in row]

KeyError: 'r'
```

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1321